# Rails - how to fetch images from S3, resize them and save thumbnails to S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, amazon-s3, resize

We have a lot of images stored in an Amazon S3 bucket and we would need to resize them. So, we would need to grab all images in the bucket and one by one resize them (according to their orientations).
What's the best way to do that? To write just a ruby script or is there any way how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I've used a combo of the [aws-sdk-ruby gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) and [rmagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick) in a worker class that:

- Downloads the original file from S3 locally
- Applies [`auto_orient`](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#auto_orient)
- Resizes it for x/y/z
- Re-uploads the orignal and the new versions back up to S3

You'd be able to queue a process like this in the background (delayed_job/sideqik/resque/etc) whenever you receive a future image.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/keighl/6866749).

Comment: It's amazing that this hasn't changed all that much in 5 years. I personally use the image_processing gem for tasks like this, but you could still use all the tools in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple shell script can also be used (with some external help)

Install [s3cmd](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd). It is a command line tool to interact with s3.
Install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). This is what rMagic uses under the hood

Then use it in a shell script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
S3CMD=$(which s3cmd)
CONVERT=$(which convert)
#
# Download the file from s3
$S3CMD get s3://mybucket/path/to/image/file.gif

# convert it to thumbnail
$CONVERT file.gif    -resize 64x64  resize_file.gif

# upload the thumbnail back to s3
$S3CMD put resize_file.git s3://mybucket/path/to/thumbnails/resize_file.gif

# cleanup
rm file.gif resize_file.gif
```

**Note:** The sample script above does not have any error checking. You should check the status code of each command before executing the next one.

ImageMagick is very powerful.

Please [see this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) for various way you can use resize an image.

You can also make thumbnails [like this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/)

s3cmd is capable of downloading all files from an s3 path. And ImageMagick is capable of batch processing (though the example script does not depict it). If you instead wish to process one image at a time, you should suitably modify the script for looping.

On the other hand, if you are already using paperclip in your application, it comes with some rake tasks. check out the documentation

```
rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails
```